# Ruby: NoMethodError without naming the undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined, nomethoderror

I'm trying to implement my first program in Ruby but I keep getting a no method error:

```
undefined method ` ' for MyString:Class (NoMethodError) from assignment.rb:1:in `<main>
```

I can't work out why or find anything online to help me solve this. I'm sure its something simple I've missed but would really appreciate help on this, thank you. My code is below.

```
class MyString

  def initialize(txt1 = "Hello, World!")
    @str = txt1
    @letters = Hash.new
  end

  def str
    @str
  end

  def letters
    @letters
  end

  def frequency
    @str.downcase.each_char.with_object({}) { |c,h|
        (h[c] = h.fetch(c,0) + 1) if c =~ /[a-z]/ }
  end

  def histogram
    @str.downcase!
    freqs = {}
    freqs.default = ''
    @str.each_char { |char| freqs[char] += '*'}
    ("a".."z").each {|x| puts "#{x} : #{freqs[x]}" }
  end

end
```

Comment: What are you doing to get the error?

Comment: You might need to post the code from assignment.rb. We need to see how your class is being used. There isn't really anything posted yet that would be causing that error.

Comment: What they said. I loaded in console and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your file for some invisible whitespace that is not a regular space .
Usually the same thing happens to me on a Mac with a german keyboard (I think on some modifier key + Space). 
The easiest thing is to open all the files in an editor in the terminal like `vim` or just `cat` them, since the special chars are often displayed there (as some strange unicode sequence).

Comment: also I guess it is in the first line, since it shows line 1 in the error (Stackoverflow kills the strange whitespaces as well I assume, so your code should look fine here to everyone)

Answer (score 0):

> NoMethodError without naming the undefined method?

The method *is* being named, it is right there in the error message between the quote marks:

```
undefined method ` ' for MyString:Class (NoMethodError) from assignment.rb:1:in `<main>
                  ↑
```

The name of the method you are trying to call is  , which is a Unicode U+AA00 non-breaking space.

You should get into the habit of reading error messages and warnings *precisely*. For example, you also missed copying the final single quote when you posted the error message here, it should say `` `<main>' `` instead of `` `<main> ``. You should also configure your editor / IDE to display whitespace.